# Non-direct measurement and degrees of freedom

Tags: descriptive-statistics, degrees-of-freedom, measurement, uncertainty

**Background and current intuition**

In statistics, degrees of freedom are used to characterise the number of independent observations after some statistic has been calculated. The most common example is that for $n$ observations the degrees of freedom are $${\nu} = n-1$$ if one has used the data to calculate the mean $\bar x$. The way I look at it is as follows. Since the mean is defined as $$\bar x = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{1}^nx_i,$$ knowing its value and the value of $n-1$ datapoints would allow one to figure out the missing observation. Okay, this seems straightforward.

**Moving ahead**

Assume we are trying to estimate the height $b$ of a building. For this, we find a level plane, measure the distance to the building (*cathetus* $a$) and to its roof (*hypothenuse* $c$). Using the Pythagorean theorem, $$b=\sqrt{c^2-a^2}.$$
Since  in the real world no measurement is absolutely accurate, we must take into account the relevant uncertainties. Again, we actually use the means of $n$ measurements ($2n$ combined), *i.e.,* $$b=\sqrt{(\bar c)^2- (\bar a)^2}.$$

This is where things start to get hairy, so please bear with me. Type C uncertainty $u_C$ for sides $a$ and $c$ is obtained via $$u_C(a)=\sqrt{[u_A(a)]^2+[u_B(a)]^2} \text{, and }u_C(c)=\sqrt{[u_A(c)]^2+[u_B(c)]^2}.$$

> $$u_A = \frac{s}{\sqrt{n}}, u_B = \frac{\text{standard error}}{\sqrt3}$$

Corresponding degrees of freedom $\nu_C(a)$ and $\nu_C(c)$ are $$\nu_C(a)=\frac{[u_C(a)]^4}{\frac{[u_A(a)]^4}{\nu_A(a)}+\frac{[u_B(a)]^4}{\nu_B(a)}}=\nu_A(a) \cdot \left[\frac{u_C(a)}{u_A(a)}\right]^4, $$ 
$$\nu_C(c)=\nu_A(c) \cdot \left[\frac{u_C(c)}{u_A(c)}\right]^4.$$

> $$\nu_A(a)=\nu_A(c)=n-1$$$$ \nu_B \to \infty$$

As if this was not difficult enough, notice we are yet to calculate the uncertainty of the height of the building. Type C uncertainty of $b$, or $u_C(b)$, is $$u_C(b)=\sqrt{\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial a}b(a;c) \cdot u_C(a) \right]^2 + \left[\frac{\partial}{\partial c}b(a;c) \cdot u_C(c) \right]^2}$$ where $b(a;c)$ emphasises that $b$ is a function of $a$ and $c$.

> $$\frac{\partial}{\partial a}b(a;c)=\frac{\partial}{\partial a}\left(\sqrt{c^2-a^2}\right)=-\frac{2a}{2\sqrt{c^2-a^2}}=-\frac{a}{\sqrt{c^2-a^2}}$$ $$\frac{\partial}{\partial c}\left(\sqrt{c^2-a^2}\right)=\frac{c}{\sqrt{c^2-a^2}}$$

Finally, we have met the necessary prerequisites to calculate the degrees of freedom of $b$ itself. Thus, $$\nu_C(b)=\frac{\left[u_C(b)\right]^4}{\frac{\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial a}b(a;\text{ }c)\text{ } \cdot\text{ } u_C(a)\right]^4 }{\nu_C(a)}+\frac{\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial c}b(a;\text{ }c) \text{ }\cdot\text{ } u_C(c)\right]^4 }{\nu_C(c)}}.$$

Sure, this needs a lot of effort. Though, still not impossible.

**Even further**

If you have stuck with me until now, you deserve a prize. And probably a little break, or a cold beverage. Or both. Assuming you are refreshened, we are not done. But we are closer than before.

Pretend we also directly measured the width $w$ of the building in question. Of course, $n$ times. We use the same formulae as before for $u_C(w)$ and $\nu_C(w)$.

> $$u_C(w)=\sqrt{[u_A(w)]^2+[u_B(w)]^2}$$$$\nu_C(w)=\nu_A(w) \cdot \left[\frac{u_C(w)}{u_A(w)}\right]^4 $$

Say we wish to know the angle $\alpha$ which is given by $$\alpha = \arctan{\frac{w}{b}}.$$

The procedure is analogous to the height.
$$u_C(\alpha)=\sqrt{\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial w}\alpha(w;b) \cdot u_C(w) \right]^2 + \left[\frac{\partial}{\partial b}\alpha(w;b) \cdot u_C(b) \right]^2}$$
$$\nu_C(\alpha)=\frac{\left[u_C(\alpha)\right]^4}{\frac{\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial w}\alpha(w;\text{ }b) \text{ }\cdot\text{ } u_C(w)\right]^4 }{\nu_C(w)}+\frac{\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial b}\alpha(w;\text{ }b)\text{ } \cdot\text{ } u_C(b)\right]^4 }{\nu_C(b)}}$$

> Here I am taking derivatives as if $b$ is not a function of $a$ and $c$. Therefore, $$\frac{\partial}{\partial w}\alpha(w;b)=\frac{\partial}{\partial w}\left(\arctan{\frac{w}{b}}\right)=\frac{1}{1+\left(\frac{w}{b}\right)^2 \cdot b} \text {,}$$ $$\frac{\partial}{\partial b}\left(\arctan{\frac{w}{b}}\right)=-\frac{w}{1+\left(\frac{w}{b}\right)^2 \cdot b^2}.$$

**Sanity check**

Be aware that I am not confident in the final two equations. This is because, theoretically, $\alpha(w,b)$ is a compound function. In other words, $$\alpha(w;b) = \alpha[w;b(a;c)] = \alpha(w;a;c).$$ It is tempting to then believe the equations should instead have the form

$$u_C(\alpha)=$$$$=\sqrt{\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial w}\alpha(w;a;c) \cdot u_C(w) \right]^2 + \left[\frac{\partial}{\partial a}\alpha(w;a;c) \cdot u_C(a) \right]^2 + \left[\frac{\partial}{\partial c}\alpha(w;a;c) \cdot u_C(c) \right]^2},$$

$$\nu_C(\alpha)=\frac{\left[u_C(\alpha)\right]^4}{\frac{\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial w}\alpha(w;\text{ }a;\text{ }c) \text{ }\cdot\text{ } u_C(w)\right]^4 }{\nu_C(w)}+\frac{\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial a}\alpha(w;\text{ }a;\text{ }c)\text{ } \cdot\text{ } u_C(a)\right]^4 }{\nu_C(a)}+\frac{\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial c}\alpha(w;\text{ }a;\text{ }c) \text{ }\cdot\text{ } u_C(c)\right]^4 }{\nu_C(c)}}.$$

**Questions**

I am cognisant of the fact that *check-my-work*-type questions are frowned upon. I hope this request is not *too much* in violation of that rule.

- **Are these approaches equivalent? Are they different? If so, which one is correct and why?**
- **Have I made a conceptual mistake somewhere else, especially with regard to degrees of freedom? What about with respect to the *Background and current intuition* section?**

**Extra**

- Be sure to comment to ask for more details if necessary.
- I was not sure whether this better belonged to [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/) or to [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/). Feel free to migrate the thread if it is the former.